# log transformation decreased model fit?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, least-squares, r-squared, logarithm

I just wondered why logged income (independent variable) decreased my model fit for OLS regression. My income distribution is skewed to the right and I am trying to transform the data. I separately ran two OLS regressions; 1) with income and income squared, and 2) with logged income, holding other things constant. Apparently, the model with log transformed income has so much lower adjusted r squared value (0.4619-> 0.0176) and higher root MSE (273.85593->370.41068) than income and income squared model.
Please let me know why this happens. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you plot your unnamed response versus income and then versus log income, it should become clear why one model works well and another does not. I can't see that skewness of income is necessarily a good reason for transformation. (If you have other predictors, which isn't clear but seems implied, the problem will be more complicated.)